# Error al sacar medias de alumnos y/o asignaturas suspensas en Java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para clase en el cual hay que pedir el número de alumnos y las asignaturas de cada alumno. Una vez que se sabe esta información, se piden las 3 notas por módulo y se hace la media solamente si tienes todas aprobadas (las 3 notas de todos los módulos).

El problema es que me hace bien la media, y me saca el error de que hay alguna suspensa, pero **sólo en las 3 últimas notas** que introduzco por teclado. Es decir, si el alumno tiene dos modulos y una de las notas está suspensa en el primer modulo, y en el segundo esta todo aprobado, me saca la media en vez del error.

```java
//CLASE ALUMNOS
package NotasAlumnos;

import utilidadaesGenerales.Utilidades;

/**
 *
 * @author Anna
 */
public class Alumno {

    private String nombre, nomAsig;
    private float nota1, nota2, nota3;
    private int cantidadMod;
    private int contador = 1;
    private float media[], mediaTotal;
    private boolean aprobado;

    public void pedirNombre() {
        nombre = Utilidades.pedirCadena("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.CYAN + "\tIntroduzca su nombre: ");
    }

    public void pedirCantModulos() {
        cantidadMod = Utilidades.pedirNumeroEntero("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.CYAN + "\t" + nombre + " ,introduzca su número de asignaturas: ");
    }

    public void pedirNotas() {
        media = new float[cantidadMod];
        aprobado = true;
        for (int cont = 0; cont < this.cantidadMod; cont++) {

            System.out.println("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.CYAN + "\t\tVamos a introudocir las notas para la asignatura " + contador++);
            nota1 = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la primera evaluación : ");
            nota2 = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la segunda evaluación:  ");
            nota3 = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca la nota de la tercera evaluación: ");

            media[cont] = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
            //mediaTotal += media;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMod; i++) {

            if (nota1 < 5 || nota2 < 5 || nota3 < 5) {
                aprobado = false;
                System.out.println("Alguna de tus evaluaciones de la asignatura " + i + "  está suspensa y tienes que ir a septiembre");

            } else {
                System.out.println("lA MEDIA DEL MODULO " + (i + 1) + " ES " + media[i] + " " + nombre);

            }

        }

        // mediaTotal /= cantidadMod;
    }

    public void pedirTodo() {
        pedirNombre();
        pedirCantModulos();
        pedirNotas();
    }

    /* public float getMedia() {
        return media;
    }*/
    public float getMediaTotal() {
        return mediaTotal;
    }

    public int getCantidadMod() {
        return cantidadMod;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getNomAsig() {
        return nomAsig;
    }

    public float getNota1() {
        return nota1;
    }

    public float getNota2() {
        return nota2;
    }

    public float getNota3() {
        return nota3;
    }

    Alumno() {
        pedirTodo();
    }
}
```

```java
//MAIN
package NotasAlumnos;

import java.util.Scanner;
import utilidadaesGenerales.Utilidades;

/**
 *
 * @author Anna
 */
public class PrincipalAlumnos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cantidadAl;
        float mediaNotas;

        Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n"+Utilidades.Colores.CYAN+"\tIntroduzca el numero de alumnos: ");
        cantidadAl = pedir.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadAl;  i++ ) {
            Alumno alum = new Alumno();



        }
```

Creo que el error es la variable de control `aprobado`, que no me está haciendo nada, pero no sé muy bien cómo funcionan las booleanas aún.

---

Y luego de las respuestas recibidas, intenté esto, pero ahora me da error!

```java
public void pedirNotas() {
    media = new float[cantidadMod];
    notas = new float [cantidadMod];
    aprobado = true;
    for (int cont = 0; cont < this.cantidadMod; cont++) {

        System.out.println("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.CYAN + "\t\tVamos a introudocir las notas para la asignatura " + contador++);
        notas[cont][0] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la primera evaluación : ");
        notas[cont][1] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la segunda evaluación:  ");
        notas[cont][2] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca la nota de la tercera evaluación: ");

        media[cont] = (notas[cont][0] + notas[cont][1] + notas[cont][2]) / 3;
        //mediaTotal += media;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMod; i++) {

        if (notas[i][0] < 5 || notas[i][1] < 5 || notas[i][2] < 5) {
            aprobado = false;
            System.out.println("Alguna de tus evaluaciones de la asignatura " + i + "  está suspensa y tienes que ir a septiembre");

        } else {
            System.out.println("lA MEDIA DEL MODULO " + (i + 1) + " ES " + media[i] + " " + nombre);

        }
```

Me da error en las líneas de

```java
 notas[cont][0] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la primera evaluación : ");
            notas[cont][1] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la segunda evaluación:  ");
            notas[cont][2] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca la nota de la tercera evaluación: ");

            media[cont] = (notas[cont][0] + notas[cont][1] + notas[cont][2]) / 3;
```

> error: array requiered, but float found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema se debe a que nota1, nota2, nota3 son compartidos entre todos los módulos, y guardarán referencia a las notas del último módulo ingresado, es decir, esta parte del código

```
...
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMod; i++) {

            if (nota1 < 5 || nota2 < 5 || nota3 < 5) {  
                aprobado = false;
                System.out.println("Alguna de tus evaluaciones de la asignatura " + i + "  está suspensa y tienes que ir a septiembre");

            } else {
                System.out.println("lA MEDIA DEL MODULO " + (i + 1) + " ES " + media[i] + " " + nombre);

            }

        }
...
```

devolverá siempre lo mismo, y será la media del último módulo, si es el caso en que aprueba, o un error caso contrario.

La solución más sencilla consiste en guardar las notas de cada módulo en un arreglo de dos dimensiones

```
public void pedirNotas() {
    media = new float[cantidadMod];
    notas = new float[cantidadMod][3]; // debes crear el campo
    aprobado = true;
    for (int cont = 0; cont < this.cantidadMod; cont++) {

        System.out.println("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.CYAN + "\t\tVamos a introudocir las notas para la asignatura " + contador++);
        notas[cont][0] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la primera evaluación : ");
        notas[cont][1] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca su nota de la segunda evaluación:  ");
        notas[cont][2] = Utilidades.pedirNumeroFloat("\n" + Utilidades.Colores.MORADO + "\t\tIntroduzca la nota de la tercera evaluación: ");

        media[cont] = (notas[cont][0] + notas[cont][1] + notas[cont][2]) / 3;
        //mediaTotal += media;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMod; i++) {

        if (notas[i][0] < 5 || notas[i][1] < 5 || notas[i][2] < 5) {
            aprobado = false;
            System.out.println("Alguna de tus evaluaciones de la asignatura " + i + "  está suspensa y tienes que ir a septiembre");

        } else {
            System.out.println("lA MEDIA DEL MODULO " + (i + 1) + " ES " + media[i] + " " + nombre);

        }

    }

    // mediaTotal /= cantidadMod;
}
```

P.D: Si empleas la solución anterior, nota1, nota2, nota3, no tendrán ningún uso, así que puedes eliminarlas de la clase Alumno, en su lugar, deberás crear un campo llamado notas, como float[][]

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar!

Answer (score 2):

En tu última respuesta estas declarando notas como unidimensional en vez de bidimensional.

Cambia

```
notas = new float [cantidadMod];
```

Por

```
notas = new float [cantidadMod][3];
```

Fijate en el ejemplo de eduen-sarceño

Comment: Sigue dando error. Incomplatble types, float [][] cannot convert to float []. :(

Comment: A la hora de declarar la variable notas tienes que ponerle que el tipo tambien es float [][]

Comment: Es cierto, perdón.. acabo de despertar jajaja. La salida del programa es correcta, cuando hay una suspensa ya no me pide notas de otras asignaturas... Quiero intentar pedir todas las notas, de todos las asignaturas aunque suspenda... si el resultado al final es que suspendió alguna que me saque el mensaje de error, y si aprobó todas que me saque la media. Mas que nada por tener un registro de todas sus notas, suspensas o no! Entiendo que el problema está en: